# ffmpeg xstack layout in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to stack a **n x n** videos in a grid using ffmpeg. eg.: 4x4, 10x10, 12x12, ... Since i have a lot of videos the ffmpeg command is generated in python and then sequentially processed.
The [xstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack) filter expects a layout, which is formated in this way:

```
xstack=inputs=16:layout=0_0|0_h0|0_h0+h1|0_h0+h1+h2|w0_0|w0_h0|w0_h0+h1|w0_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4_0|
w0+w4_h0|w0+w4_h0+h1|w0+w4_h0+h1+h2|w0+w4+w8_0|w0+w4+w8_h0|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1|w0+w4+w8_h0+h1+h2
```

For layouts with few videos i wrote the xstack filter by hand but for 60x60 videos it is unreasonable.

How can I generate the layout string in python given a grid of equal rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

For a fully populated grid, you can use `interleave` and `tile` filters to greatly simplify filtergraph expression. Something like...

```
[0:v]...[3599:v]interleave=3600,tile=60x60
```

caveat: This assumes all inputs to have the same framerate and same length. `interleave` could be very finicky if input frames don't align properly.

I do not know how the performance of this chain compares to `xstack` though.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this to generate the layout string for the xstack filter. It is messy though:

```
n =4

layout_col = ["h0"]
for i in range(n-2):
    current_col = "h" + str(i+1)
    current_col = layout_col[-1]+"+"+current_col
    layout_col.append(current_col)
layout_col.insert(0,"0")

layout_row = ["w0"] 
for i in range(n-2):
    current_row = "w"+str((i+1)*n)
    current_row = layout_row[-1]+"+"+current_row
    layout_row.append(current_row)
layout_row.insert(0,"0")

layout = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        comb =   layout_row[i] + "_" + layout_col[j] 
        layout.append(comb)
layout = "|".join(layout)
layout = "xstack=inputs="+str(n)+":layout="+layout

print (layout)
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, maybe a comment, if you want to add something additionally add it on your question.

Comment: why isn't it an answer? it does the thing I asked for and can be used as is. Coding style is debatable but it works

Comment: You tried to answer your own question, my advice in this case is that it will be better to add this to your question as a maybe fix. The other problem here is that you do not explain anything regarding your answer. If another user finds this he won't have any idea why you did this...